# How to accept more sentences by sphinx4

Tags: macos, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm using Sphinx4 version 4-1.0beta6 over my mac osx 10.9.1 through the terminal.
I'm still new in this SR application. I've already run HelloWrold example and added some new words to the gram file and it worked. Now, I'd like to use rules or something that helps in order to accept more sentences spoken by the user. My questions are:

- How Can I make my HelloWorld do that? Should I use rules? and if so, is there any examples?
- If I used rules, How can I print the spoken question back to the user?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this for Sphinx Search - http://sphinxsearch.com/ ?

Comment: For this: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Can I make my HelloWorld do that? Should I use rules? and if so, is there any examples?

It depends on the task but generally you want to extend the grammar with more rules. You can find more information in CMUSphinx tutorial at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

> If I used rules, How can I print the spoken question back to the user?

You get the recognition result as string. You can print it with System.out.println or display in your UI or do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, Can u please give the name of the tutorial where they have used rules in the grammar? Thanks again

Comment: Sphinx4 tutorial is at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4. The grammar tutorial is at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm. The Dialog demo uses grammars.

Comment: Thanks a lot! in my case I'm using sphinx to get the text from the user speech to retrieve information from sample DB. the range of user speech is not very big yet not very small. what kind of method I should use?(I mean web service or language model toolkit)

Comment: You can use web service

Comment: Thanks again Nikolay. I'll read more about it. thanks for the help!